# How to uninstall vim on mac?

Tags: mac, vim, github

I installed vim on my Mac by using the git clone command:

```
https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
```

However now I want to remove it and re-install vim via homebrew.

Could any expert tell me how to remove it on my Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: I am just a beginner so haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Have you tried the normal Mac uninstall methods? Have you done some basic searching online to find how to uninstall?

Comment: @music2myear All the answers I found online are based on homebrew, which is "brew uninstall vim". So I really don't know how to remove vim installed from github.

Comment: Make has its own uninstall capability, I believe. If you installed vim using Make, you should research removing it the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've compiled from souce, you should just navigate to the source directory and run the make uninstall command, since you've compiled from source using `make`. Something like:

```
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim73
make uninstall
```

should work.

More details on how to uninstall using make here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li

**EDIT:** 
From the above link,

You can manually remove vim by running `make -n install` to find out the steps used to install vim and manually remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive instruction. Much appreciated!

Comment: I hope this worked.

Answer (score 0):

`$ make` doesn't *install* Vim, it *builds* it without adding, removing, or changing anything on your system.

This means that you can install Vim with homebrew or any other method without caring about the Vim you built from source. And that you can safely delete the Vim source.

Comment: How do you know that running `make` doesn't change anything on my system, outside of the `vim/src` directory, which contains the `Makefile`?

Comment: I know it because I've read, edited, and executed that `Makefile` many times in the past. All `$ make` does is build Vim in `vim/src`; it doesn't *install* it or any of its dependency. To *install* the Vim you just built you need to do `$ sudo make install`. Since the OP only did `$ make`, nothing happened outside of `vim/`: **Vim was not installed so he doesn't have to do *anything***.